# Why do the welcome and software boutique features not completely load?

Tags: software-boutique

PC Details,
IBM MT-M 8189 34U,
Memory 2.0 Gib,,
Processor Intel Pentium®  4 CPU 2.80GHz,
Graphics Gallium 0.4 on lvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits),
Disks IDE 40 GiB Master 60 GiB Slave,
O.S. Ubuntu Mate 18.04

The windows open for both apps from wherever I launch them including as root in the terminal. From there I get nothing but a white empty space. I have tried reinstalling the OS and the individual apps, no luck. I am out of ideas please help. Thanks